# Accessing the content of a variable array with ctypes

Tags: python, pointers, multidimensional-array, ctypes

I use ctypes to access a file reading C function in python. As the read data is huge and unknown in size I use `**float` in C .

`int read_file(const char *file,int *n_,int *m_,float **data_) {...}`

The functions `mallocs` an 2d array, called `data`, of the appropriate size, here `n` and `m`, and copies the values to the referenced ones. See following snippet:

```
*data_ = data;
*n_ = n;
*m_ = m;
```

I access this function with the following python code:

```
p_data=POINTER(c_float)
n=c_int(0)
m=c_int(0)
filename='datasets/usps'
read_file(filename,byref(n),byref(m),byref(p_data))
```

Afterwards I try to acces `p_data` using `contents`, but I get only a single float value.

```
p_data.contents
c_float(-1.0)
```

**My question is: How can I access `data` in python?**

What do you recommended? Please don't hesitate to point out if I left something unclear!

Comment: +1 for ctypes, the best python library

Answer (score 3):

might be simpler to do the whole thing in python with the `struct` library. but if you're sold on ctypes (and I don't blame you, it's pretty cool):

```
#include <malloc.h>
void floatarr(int* n, float** f)
{
    int i;
    float* f2 = malloc(sizeof(float)*10);
    n[0] = 10;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    { f2[i] = (i+1)/2.0; }
    f[0] = f2;
}
```

and then in python:

```
from ctypes import *

fd = cdll.LoadLibrary('float.dll')
fd.floatarr.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int),POINTER(POINTER(c_float))]

fpp = POINTER(c_float)()
ip = c_int(0)
fd.floatarr(pointer(ip),pointer(fpp))
print ip
print fpp[0]
print fpp[1]
```

the trick is that capitals `POINTER` makes a type and lowercase `pointer` makes a pointer to existing storage. you can use `byref` instead of `pointer`, they claim it's faster. I like `pointer` better because it's clearer what's happening.

Comment: You can also use ctypes to parse binary files.  I find it a little easier to work with then the struct module.

Comment: Hi Amwinter, your answer already made me understand more, but I have two questions left. 

1. I read `15.16.1.7. Specifying the required argument types` from http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html and I don't understand why `argtypes` is needed. I tried my example without using it and it worked as well.

2. I mentioned it in the `tags` but forgot to do so in the actual questions. How would this work when data would be of more than one dimension? I tried `print p_data[0][0]` but I got an `TypeError: 'float' object is unsubscriptable`.

Comment: Hi @amwinter, I can see you are very experimented  in Python can you help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377764/error-using-callback-in-python), please?