# Error using callback in Python

Tags: python, c++, error-handling, callback, char

I am developing a dll that should be used in Python. I have a callback function to send my parameters (defined in a separate header):

`typedef int(*call_nBest)(char **OutList, float* confList, int nB);`

So, I'm using this callback in this way:

```
#define TEXT_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE 50
call_nBest nBestList;
void Xfunction(const char* aLineThatWillBeConvertedInAList){
    char **results;
    float *confidences;
    confidences=new float[nBest];
    results=new char*[nBest];
    for(int i=0; i<nBest; i++) results[i]=new char[TEXT_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE];

    MakeLine2List(aLineThatWillBeConvertedInAList,results,confidences); 

    /*At this function I am having the error :(*/
    nBestList(results,confidences,nBest); // Passing the values to my callback

    for(int i=0; i<nBest; i++) delete [] results[i];
    delete [] confidences;
    delete [] results;

}
```

And I'm exporting it in this way:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int ResultCallback(call_nBest theList){
    nBestList = theList;
    return(0);
}
```

I tested my callback first in another C++ application in this way:

```
int MyCallback(char **OutLi, float* confLi, int nB){
    printf("\n The nB results: %d \n",nB);
    for(int n=0; n<nB; n++){
        std::cout << *(confLi+n) << "\t" << OutLi[n] << "\n";
    }
    return(0);
}
```

In `main()` I give the callback in this way:

```
ResultCallback(MyCallback);
```

and it works pretty well. But I don't have any idea how to adapt this to Python. I have tried this:

**Note:** I have changed the last way, because I resolved some mistakes, but I'm still getting an error. This is the current way of how I am loading `myDLL`

```
from ctypes import *
def callbackU(OutList,ConList,nB):
    for i in range(nB):
        print(OutList[i][0:50]) #I don't know how to print the values
return 0

myDLL = cdll.LoadLibrary("MyLibrary.dll")

calling = CFUNCTYPE(c_int,POINTER(POINTER(c_char)),POINTER(c_float),c_int)
theCall= calling(callbackU)
myDLL.ResultCallback(theCall)

myDLL.StartProcess(); #In this process the given callback will be invoqued
```

### ERROR

And now I have this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to
>   read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other
>   memory is corrupt.    at Xfunction(SByte*
>   aLineThatWillBeConvertedInAList)
>
> #### Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH
>    Application Name:    python.exe
>    Application Version: 0.0.0.0
>    Application Timestamp:   54f9ed12
>    Fault Module Name:   MSVCR100.dll
>    Fault Module Version:    10.0.40219.325
>    Fault Module Timestamp:  10.0.40219.325
>    Exception Code:  c0000005
>    Exception Offset:    00001ed7
>    OS Version:  6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.4
>    Locale ID:   1033
>    Additional Information 1:    5861
>    Additional Information 2:    5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
>    Additional Information 3:    a10f
>    Additional Information 4:    a10ff7d2bb2516fdc753f9c34fc3b069

#### Things that I've done and are almost what I want:

First I changed the callback Python function for this one:

```
def callbackU(OutList,ConList,nB):
    for i in range(nB):
        print(i)
return 0
```

All works with no error and I can see this in the Console (in this case `nB` was `10`):

```
0
1
...
9
```

Second, I changed the function as this one:

```
def callbackU(OutList,ConList,nB):
    for i in range(nB):
        print (cast(OutList,c_char_p))
return 0
```

and, oh surprise this prints only the first word of the list (nB times)

Comment: Can you upload a compilable example or your dll? It's a bit hard to debug otherwise.

Comment: At this moment I'm not able to do that, but I can give all information you need

Comment: @simonzack, I have made some changes and the problem doesn't look as bigger as I thaught

Comment: Where are you defining `nBest`?

Comment: @Jhon In a header file

Comment: What version of Python are you using? 2.x? 3.x?

Comment: I am using Python 3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
def callbackU(OutList, ConList, nB):
    for i in range(nB):
        print("{}\t{}".format(ConList[i], cast(OutList[i], c_char_p)))
    return 0
```

From what I understand you're just trying to match the output of your Python `callbackU` function with your C++ `MyCallback` function.

Python has a variety of [string formatting functionality](https://pyformat.info/) that can be confusing at first, but pays homage to `printf` string formatting.

Since `OutList` has type `LP_LP_c_char` (pointer to pointer of `c_char`, vs "NULL terminated `char *`" `c_char_p`), we'd best turn it into a native Python data type like so:

```
def callbackU(OutList, ConList, nB):
    for i in range(nB):
        out_list_item = cast(OutList[i], c_char_p).value
        print("{}\t{}".format(ConList[i], out_list_item))
    return 0
```

Comment: Hi, I'm testing your answer, and this is what I got with `nB=1`: `0.3946000039577484      c_char_p(b"I'M")`. Pretty good!, but I don't like the `c_char_p()` phrase in the text, can you fix it?

Comment: I don't really have enough information to replicate your scenario, but it looks like you might be able to get what you want with `OutList[i].value` or `cast(OutList[i], c_char_p).value`. If you still get the `b"..."`, then you can `decode` the byte string into a normal Python 3 Unicode string with `b"...".decode('utf8')`

Comment: Using `OutList[i].value` gave me this error: `---> 23         print("{}\t{}".format(ConfList[i], OutList[i].value))
        global print.format = undefined
        ConfList = <ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_float object at 0x0F9F9D50>
        i = 0
        OutList = <__main__.LP_LP_c_char object at 0x0DE678F0>
        i.value = undefined`

Comment: Using `cast(OutList[i],c_char_p).value` gave me this error: `---> 22         print("{}\t{}".format(ConfList[i], cast(OutList[i], c_char_p)).value)
        global print.format = undefined
        ConfList = <ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_float object at 0x0FA23B70>
        i = 0
        global cast = <function cast at 0x0273AA98>
        OutList = <__main__.LP_LP_c_char object at 0x0DAB5760>
        global c_char_p.value = <attribute 'value' of '_ctypes._SimpleCData' objects>`

Comment: and using `decode` gave me this error: `22         c=cast(OutList[i], c_char_p)
---> 23         print("{}\t{}".format(ConfList[i], c.decode('uft-8')))
        global print.format = undefined
        ConfList = <ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_float object at 0x0DF08710>
        i = 0
        c.decode = undefined
     24         #print("{}\t{}".format(ConfList[i], OutList[i].value))
     25     return 0

AttributeError: 'c_char_p' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: In your second comment, you've got `print("{}\t{}".format(ConfList[i], cast(OutList[i], c_char_p)).value)`, which is not right. I meant `print("{}\t{}".format(ConfList[i], cast(OutList[i], c_char_p).value))`. Note the single parenthesis before `value`. I'll update my answer to show this more clearly.