# Python/Ctypes - Segmentation Fault on Access to Pointer (to Array)

Tags: python, c, pointers, segmentation-fault, ctypes

[This is similar except I do not get a single value and instead segfault on [0] or .contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620348/accessing-the-content-of-a-variable-array-with-ctypes?lq=1)

**How can I access the elements in 'array' from Python?**

In C I have something like

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Data {
    int i;
    int *array;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

typedef struct {
    bool (* const get)   (struct Data*, const char *source);
    void (* const print) (struct Data*);
} DataFn;
extern DataFn const DATAFUNC;
```

In Python I have something like

```
class Data(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("i", ctypes.c_int),
        ("array",   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
    ]

class DATA_FN(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("get"   , ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
                                          ctypes.c_bool,
                                          ctypes.POINTER(Data),
                                          ctypes.c_char_p)),
        ("print" , ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, 
                                          ctypes.POINTER(Data)))
    ]
```

From python I can do something like ..

```
    with open("xx0c.exx", "rb") as f:
        fdata = f.read()
        dfn.get(ctypes.byref(data),f fdata)
        dfn.print(ctypes.byref(data))
        print(data)
        print(data.i)                #7, correct
        #print(data.array.contents)  #segfault
        #print(data.array)           #segfault
        ptr = ctypes.pointer(data)
        print(ptr.contents.array[0]) #segfault
```

C function called from python will print .. which is correct

> i = 7
>
> array = 0x6ffff360034
>
> array 0 = 20
>
> array 1 = 27a40
>
> array 2 = 127e20
>
> array 3 = 128ae0
>
> array 4 = 47e850
>
> array 5 = 57ec30
>
> array 6 = 580230

I can see the array in python isn't anywhere near the array in C.

Sample C code as asked. These are static, but they can be accessed through DATAFUNC. The C programs that use these are fine.

```
static bool getdata(struct Data *d, const char *filedata) {
    bool good = false;
    if (d != NULL && filedata != NULL) {
        d -> i       = (int32_t)filedata[0];
        d -> array   = (uint32_t*)(filedata + sizeof(int32_t));
        if ( d->i > 0 ) {
          good = true;
        }
    }
    return good;
}

static void printdata(struct Data *d) {
    if (d == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    printf("i = %i\n", d -> i);
    printf("array = %p\n", d -> array);
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < d -> i; i++) {
        printf("array %i = %x\n", i, d -> array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your C code as well? It could be that the error is there.

Comment: I'm willing to, but as a warning it's working correctly for C programs that include it (it's also specific for a binary file format).

Comment: Are you reading the file inside a Python function? Because then the variable `file` will be local to that function, and its lifetime ends when the function end, making your pointer to the data invalid.

Comment: Yes it's read in the function. The portions posted here are technically together in the script, but segmented for formatting in the post & to show outputs for each line.

Comment: Then that's most likely your problem. Dynamically allocate memory to hold a *copy* of the data, and add functions to release this data when it's not needed anymore.

Comment: I disagree. The C function is designed to use memory of the buffer that stores file contents instead of copying an extra segment and allocating to heap. We can see that it works correctly by calling the C function 'print', but the problem manifests when python tries to access data that would be returned by the get function.

Comment: If the data pointed to by the `array` member no longer exists, which might happen if the Python variable goes out of scope and is garbage-collected, then the pointer becomes invalid. Dereferencing it in *any* way leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which makes all further speculation about behavior useless.

Comment: Please check the indents.

Comment: Okay, didn't see your latest edits. Now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue by adding *pack* to the python struct like as follows.

```
class Data(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_   = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("i", ctypes.c_int),
        ("array",   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
    ]
```

This fixes everything and gives the output of .. once a loop was added to iterate through arrays.

```
number of offsets = 7
offsets = 0x6ffff360034
offset 0 = 20
offset 1 = 27a40
offset 2 = 127e20
offset 3 = 128ae0
offset 4 = 47e850
offset 5 = 57ec30
offset 6 = 580230
<__main__.Data object at 0x6ffffd5f400>
7
<__main__.LP_c_int object at 0x6ffffd5f488>
0x20
0x27a40
0x127e20
0x128ae0
0x47e850
0x57ec30
0x580230
```